# How to redirect a subdomain link?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to make a redirect in case people didn't type in the complete link to my subdomain, something like:

28cup.mpkosis28.com/ to redirect to 28cup.mpkosis28.com/index.html

I tried to make a default redirect in cpanel, but it still won't redirect.

EDIT: So I made a subdomain: http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/index.html. The problem is that I have to add the /index.html every time I want to access the site without going to mpkosis28.com first. I don't want to tell people that they have to add the /index.html if they want to go directly into the site, I can just tell them to go to 28cup.mpkosis28.com which redirects to 28cup.mpkosis28.com/index.html.

Sorry for not adding more details in the question, it's because of some question "guidelines".

Comment: That's the default behavior for apache.

Comment: Your question is not really clear... Give more examples please.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: The way you're asking now, is going to end up in an endless loop. `index.html` is the/a default server file. `../index.html` won't do anything, it has nowhere else to go. Your question is unclear. Basic redirect is `Redirect folder/file.xxx other.xxx` in `.htaccess` - Don't ask "something like...", show us what you want.

Comment: @woz It seems he wants to redirect (for some reason), not simply load the index file.  And, there's no indication he's using Apache.

Comment: I'll bet you want to redirect `http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/` to `http://mpkosis28.com/28cup.php` am I right? Or to `http://mpkosis28.com/index.html` - So hard playing golf at midnight while using black balls and aiming for a dark hole.

Comment: Added details. Sorry for not putting them in the question, for some reason it won't let me post that way.

Comment: In `.htaccess` do `Redirect http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/ http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/index.html` should do the trick. @hiu28

Answer (score 1):

If on an Apache server, create a file called `.htaccess` and insert the following:

```
Redirect http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/ http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/index.html
```

then upload in ASCII format in either the root of the sub-domain, and/or the root of `mpkosis28.com`

You can also try using:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: Still can't redirect, when I type http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/ it turns into http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Comment: Did you (or do you) already have an `.htaccess` file residing in either the sub-domain `28cup.mpkosis28.com` or the the domain `mpkosis28.com`? @hiu28

Comment: I did click on http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/ and even without the `http://` and it did remain unchanged with no redirection to http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi and saw a coming soon with a scooter. So, I think it may be something local to you. @hiu28 But when I clicked on http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/contact.html it brings/redirects me back to http://28cup.mpkosis28.com/index.html so you may not have done it correctly in Cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code below in the head of your the index or the default page visitor would normally go.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http//subdomain.domain.com">`

For instance if when visitors type `www.domain.com` you want them to be redirected to `http//subdomain.domain.com` you will put `http//subdomain.domain.com`as the value of the `URL`   in the code.

Comment: This is not the proper way to handle a redirect.  Do it at the HTTP level, with a 301 or 302 status code and a location header so that all HTTP clients can follow it... not just ones that parse HTML and understand meta tags.